# Lambda SQL error trying to retrieve single column

Tags: lambda, linq-to-entities

```
Dim alist
    Using db As New Entities
 alist = From v In db.VideoUrls.Where(Function(v) v.CausedError = 0 And v.BeenDownloaded = 0) Select v.FileUrl.Take(Tb_Files2Download.Text)
        End Using
```

My intent is to return only a list of the urls (v.FileUrl) for the given criteria. I can pull the entire entity, but I only need the single column FileUrl returned.

Error inside query results is 'DirectCast(alist, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery(Of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Char))).Sql' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you linqpad for a more detailed error message.. I was trying to apply the take() operator on the wrong part of the sequence the code should have read.

```
(From v In VideoUrls.Where(Function(v) v.CausedError = 0 And v.BeenDownloaded = 0)Select v.FileUrl).take(10)
```

Seems odd to start a statement with a paren  but all things being equal...
Hope this can help someone else.